# How to reset an animation on stop to its initial state in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

What I want to do is when I stop an animation to 
reset the initial state of the animated object. I want to do that because when I stop it now (`Element.stop([anim])`) it freezes in its current point (lets say half tranperant) and when I play it again the animation starts to repeat from this place not from the beginning.

Here is my animation `Raphael.animation({opacity: 0}, 500, "<>").repeat(Infinity)`.

I asked this question in the Raphael newsgroup 3 weeks ago but I didn't receive any answer.

Thanks, 
bozhidarc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not suggesting it's the most elegant, but in the past I've done things like this simply by adding a couple of extra attributes to the element when you create it. In this case, I'd just add a baseAttrs attribute, which holds the original object of settings:

```
    var paper = Raphael('canvas', 500, 500);

    var circle = paper.circle(320, 240, 60);
    circle.baseAttrs = {fill:'yellow'}; // add to the elem
    circle.attr(circle.baseAttrs);

    circle.animate({fill: "blue"}, 1000,
                   function(){
                       this.attr(this.baseAttrs);
                   });
```

In the above example, the callback from the animation sets the attributes of the circle to the `baseAttrs`value of the element when the animation is complete. The `baseAttrs` will always be held with the circle, regardless of what happens to it. http://jsfiddle.net/UVPeh/